# Spring Security как настроить права доступа

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, аутентификация

Я новичок. Пытаюсь сделать по туториалу приложение на Spring Boot с Spring Security, но так, чтобы регистрация и аутентификации не были обязательными для просмотра страниц. Пытался искать решение в интернете, но либо ничего не понял, либо сделал, но не работает (например выставил `anyRequest().permitAll()`) и все равно перебрасывает на страницу login. Вот мой WebSecurityConfig:

```
package config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import service.UserService;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("removal")
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.
        csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
    .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz.anyRequest().permitAll()
                    //Доступ только для не зарегистрированных пользователей
                    .requestMatchers("/registration").not().fullyAuthenticated()
                    //Доступ только для пользователей с ролью Администратор
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                  
                    
                    
                
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                    //Настройка для входа в систему
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    //Перенарпавление на главную страницу после успешного входа
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/"));
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

UPD. Попробовал еще добавить `.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()` - то же самое

UPD. Я только сейчас заметил, что я скорее всего напортачил где-то в другом месте, так как если я пытаюсь запретить доступ к login странице, приложение на это не реагирует и все равно разрешает к ней доступ: `.formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().` Где я еще мог что-то не так сделать?

Comment: Те страницы, к которым вы хотите обеспечить доступ всем, также надо явно прописать в данной цепочке. Например, если вы хотите, чтобы все могли просматривать страницу `page`, то надо написать `.requestMatchers("/page").permitAll()`. Кстати, это же надо прописать в том числе и на `login` и `registration`, а то пользователь никогда не сможет зайти.

Comment: На страницу login я успешно захожу. Может я в другом месте мог что-то не доделать? А если у меня будет скажем 50 страниц, не прописывать же их все в этом классе.

Comment: Попробовал еще добавить `.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()` - то же самое

Comment: А попробуйте убрать дублирование `.anyRequest().permitAll()`, вы его два раза написали: в начале и в конце.

Comment: Я знаю. Я специально так сделал на всякий случай, когда другие действия не помогали. Все равно не работает.

Comment: Я только сейчас заметил, что я скорее всего напортачил где-то в другом месте, так как если я пытаюсь запретить доступ к login странице, приложение на это не реагирует и все равно разрешает к ней доступ: ```.formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()```. Где я еще мог что-то не так сделать?